# how to extract words from the string in the list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, web-scraping

I have a string of type

```
string = "[A] Assam[B] Meghalaya[C] West Bengal[D] Odisha "

Output = ['Assam', 'Meghalaya','West Bengal','Odhisa']
```

I tried many ways, but I always end up splitting the substring West Bengal into two halves...
I am not able to cover the edge case mentioned above.

What I tried was pass the string into the below function and then split it.. But not working!!!!

```
def remove_alpha(string):

    option = ['[A]', '[B]', '[C]', '[D]']
    res = ""
    for i in option:
        res = string.replace(i, '')
        string = res
    return res
```

Comment: You didn't explain what you want ? What is the expected output ?

Comment: i have explained that... check the output that's what i want..

Comment: One-liner: `[b for a in s.split(']') if (b := a.partition('[')[0].strip())]` (requires python >= 3.8).

Comment: You said "I have", that is unclear that the second line would be what you expect

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex for this:

```py
import re

string = "[A] Assam[B] Meghalaya[C] West Bengal[D] Odisha "
pattern = re.compile(r"] (.*?)(?:\[|$)")

output = pattern.findall(string.strip())
print(output)
# ['Assam', 'Meghalaya', 'West Bengal', 'Odisha']
```

- How it works: https://regex101.com/r/5peFyC/1
- [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module

Comment: If you don't mind! Can you explain this lil-bit??

Comment: @AnshumanSharma which part exactly? Explanation about regex (how the pattern works) is given in the link after _How it works:_, you can find what [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) do in the docs I sent (or for ease of access click on the names in this comment, they will take you to the according docs)

Comment: thanks man!! This is the first time i have seen a regex expression… I have to learn regex.. Any suggestions where can i learn??

Comment: @AnshumanSharma This [tutorial on regex by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa-TUpSx1JA), this [tutorial on `re` by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8L6KVGG-7o), this [HOWTO in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) and just the [documentation of `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (includes explanation for each character and stuff), as well as https://regex101.com/ for practice, explanation and other stuff

Comment: The above solution does not work for the original string given in the question. In order to work as expected it is necessary to remove the trailing space from the original string (for example using `.strip()`)

Comment: @Claudio yeah, fixed that, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

You can split on regex patterns using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```py
import re


string = "[A] Assam[B] Meghalaya[C] West Bengal[D] Odisha "

print(re.split(r"\s*\[\w\]\s*", string.strip())[1:])
```

Note that we first eliminate the spaces around the string by `strip()`, then we use `r"\s*\[\w\]\s*"` to match up options like `[A]` with possible spaces. Since the first element of the result is empty, we remove that by slicing `[1:]` at the end.

Comment: In case of the given string `r"\[\w\] "` would do it too.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a one-line list-comprehension plus a special case of the last option:

```
[string[string.find(option[i]):string.find(option[i+1])].split(option[i])[1].strip() for i in range(len(option) - 1)] + [string.split(option[-1])[1].strip()]
```

Broken down into a loop, with some explicit intermediate steps for readability:

```
res = []
for i in range(len(option) - 1):    
    from_ind = string.find(option[i]) 
    to_ind = string.find(option[i+1])
    sub_str = string[from_ind:to_ind]
    clean_sub_str = sub_str.split(option[i])[1].strip()
    res.append(clean_sub_str)

# Last option add-on
res.append(string.split(option[-1])[1].strip())    
print(res)
# ['Assam', 'Meghalaya', 'West Bengal', 'Odisha']
```

This is not as pretty as using regex, but allows for more flexibility in defining the "options".

Comment: Don't you think it's very unreadable?

Comment: You're right :-)  Broke the list-comp into an explicit loop for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string using regular expression `re.split()` which is much more powerful compared to Python strings `.split()` adjusting the obtained
result using a list comprehension.

*The provided solution does not require to modify the input string before splitting and works also in case the input string comes with overall spread whitespaces as demonstrated below:*

```
import re
s = "  [A] Assam[B] Meghalaya [C] West Bengal [D] Odisha  "
print([ r.strip() for r in re.split("\[[A-Z]\]", s) if r.strip() ] )
# gives: ['Assam', 'Meghalaya', 'West Bengal', 'Odisha']
```

- The regex pattern `r'\[[A-Z]\]'` splits on `'[A]'` up to `'[Z]'`
- `r.strip()` removes any white spaces enclosing the results
- `if r.strip()` removes empty strings and strings containing only spaces from the result of splitting
- The backslash in `'\['` and `'\]'` is necessary as square brackets have a special meaning when using regular expression pattern and must be escaped
- `[A-Z]` represents any of uppercase ASCII letters from A up to Z